# How Far Is Too Far When Turning The Potentiometer On The GameCube Disc Drive?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

Today, I repaired a GameCube that had DRE by turning the potentiometer on the disc drive board about a quarter turn counterclockwise (it now looks like a "+" slanted slightly to the left) to increase the power of the laser that reads the discs, as I've heard others have had success with. However, I've also heard that giving the laser too much power can damage discs permanently over time. My question is, how far is too far when turning the potentiometer?

Comment: I really like this question, but I get the feeling it's outside the scope of Arqade.  [Super User](http://superuser.com/) says they aren't about video game consoles, but if you broaden your question from Gamecube optical drives to optical drives in general, I think you'd find better answers there.

Comment: Because I'm super interested in this though, drop a link to the new question in the comments!  I want to see if it goes anywhere!

Comment: @Gendreavus I suspect you're right. I'll ask this question there. Update: I just took the post I made there down. It was already at -3 before even being up an hour. Perhaps this issue is too GameCube specific.

Comment: I am not sure wether a GameCube is old enough for retrogaming.SE. What does DRE stand for?

Comment: @Polygnome Disc Read Error

Comment: You don't need to react to early downvotes.  There are always "purists" jumping on new and odd questions.  Let it stew a bit and see if there are useful comments.  I'll delete it only if it gets closed and also a pile of downvotes.  Mention that you just want to fix the optical drive.  The fact that it is on GameCube is secondary.